# Is there any way to convert markdown to asciidoc (or be able to produce the same HTML output)?

Tags: html, converters, markdown, docbook, asciidoc

Here is my problem, normally I convert asciidoc documents to HTML (or more precisely asciidoc --> docbook --> html) but here I've been given a markdown document.

I would like to be able to produce an HTML document from that markdown document that would look the same as if it was coming from an asciidoc OR be able to convert this markdown to asciidoc somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Try](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) to use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert the markdown source to docbook xml.

From there, it should be possible to convert the docbook xml to html with the same technique as you used before for the asciidoc input, e.g. use the same xslt-translations for docbook->html.

Comment: The latest version of Pandoc (in the repo) allows for asciidoc <-> markdown transormations.

Answer (score 44):

To echo @akosma comment, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) does indeed have [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) support:

```
# Convert to AsciiDoc from Markdown:
$ pandoc -t asciidoc -f markdown file1.md > file1.txt
```

You can also go directly from Markdown to HTML:

```
$ pandoc -S -t html -f markdown file1.md > file1.html
```

(The `-S` just to produce nice curly quotes and other Smart typographical changes)

Comment: I think it is kind of abandoned at this point unfortunately, e.g. it has some glaring bugs: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4362

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Pandoc doesn't convert a lot of documents correctly, so I've created my own converter, which can be found [here](https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc).

It's a simple tool written in Java which has been successfully used to convert a lot of documents, including the manual from [Geb](http://www.gebish.org).

Comment: I have a quite extensive suite here https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc/tree/master/src/test/resources/com/laamella/markdown_to_asciidoc Run them on Pandoc, and all failings tests are issues.

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw another one into the mix. I've written a custom converter for Kramdown that converts Markdown to AsciiDoc.

https://github.com/opendevise/kramdown-asciidoc

The benefit of this library is that Kramdown is extremely good at parsing GitHub-flavored Markdown, which is likely the Markdown people are most interested converting from.

Comment: Speaking from experience as a technical writer and user of the package, kramdown-asciidoc is far more suited to converting Markdown to Asciidoc than Pandoc. If you're interested, I wrote a post on the package that gives a reasonably in-depth look at the package and how to use it: https://matthewsetter.com/convert-markdown-to-asciidoc-with-kramdown-asciidoc/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best pandoc solution:

```
pandoc --atx-headers --verbose --wrap=none --toc --reference-links -s -f markdown -t asciidoc -o file.adoc README.md
```

The version I used is `pandoc 2.11.0.4`.